# Display parts of data from array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

i have a system which connects to the db to retrieve the top 5 (by date) results in the articles table. This pulls the results and stores them with the details id, title, summary and content. so 5 results with 4 pieces of information.

index.php should then include this information and display into home.html.php... my issue is that when i do this i get multiple lines of the same data. I am trying to get it to display the newest article as a main feature and then others as sub news on the page.

index.php

```
try{
                    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY publicationDate DESC LIMIT 0,5';
                    $result = $pdo->query($sql);


                }

            catch (PDOException $e){
                $error = 'Error fetching jokes: ' . $e->getMessage();
                include 'error.html.php';
                exit();
                }

            foreach ($result as $row){
                $articles[] = array(
                'id' => $row['id'], 
                'title' => $row['title'],
                'summary' => $row['summary'],
                'content' => $row['content']);

                }

            include '/templates/ui/home.html.php';
```

home.html.php

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
  <?php foreach ($articles as $article):?>
    <h1><?php htmlout($article['title'] ); ?></h1>
    <p><?php htmlout($article['summary'] );?></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2><?php htmlout($article['title'] ); ?></h2>
      <p><?php htmlout($article['summary'] );?> </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2><?php htmlout($article['title'] ); ?></h2>
      <p><?php htmlout($article['summary'] );?> </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
   </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2><?php htmlout($article['title'] ); ?></h2>
      <p><?php htmlout($article['summary'] );?></p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>

    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
```

i hope there is enough information, just want to know how i can pull out parts of the array that i require so that each of these entries is different.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a dozen ways to do this. I would use array_shift and to get the first article from the array. Then move the foreach loop down to where you have the class="col-md-4" divs, a la

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <div class="container">
  <?php $firstArticle = array_shift($articles); // this takes the first one off the array ?>
    <h1><?php htmlout($firstArticle['title'] ); ?></h1>
    <p><?php htmlout($firstArticle['summary'] );?></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <?php 
    // the remaining four articles can be accessed with the foreach
    foreach ($articles as $article):?>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2><?php htmlout($article['title'] ); ?></h2>
      <p><?php htmlout($article['summary'] );?> </p>
      <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you notice, you don't have to repeat the html that is inside the loop. The loop repeats it for you.

Comment: Hi Russell Thank you very much for your assistance on this. Your solution works an absolute treat and least over i understand how which is fantastic for me... i was having issues with unspecified variables when i tried this idea originally and moved away from it.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you may access array elements by index. Remove the `foreach` and use `$articles[0]` for the main article, and `$articles[1]` and so on for the rest.

You may improve the code using `array_slice` function to extract the *sub-news* and use a `foreach` to avoid repeating the code for each of them.

Answer (score 0):

I would debug this portion of the code to make sure you're getting what you're expecting, do a print_r or var_dump on $result before the loop. Put an exit() after the test so it doesn't execute any other parts of the code while debugging:

```
    foreach ($result as $row){
        $articles[] = array(
        'id' => $row['id'], 
        'title' => $row['title'],
        'summary' => $row['summary'],
        'content' => $row['content']);

        }
```

You're read out to the template looks good. I'm curious why you're getting lines of the same data.

Checklist:

- Have you checked the DB to make sure that the data is in there?
- Why don't you have `$result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);` before the 
  foreach loop?

Comment: Thank you for this also i have been looking at adding logging to my code to help with the development but also moving forward... will give these (print_r and var_dump) a go to see if i can see how i can use these.. thank you again

Answer (score 0):

Why you just don't do this in the index.php? 

Of this way you avoid create an array of an array.

```
<?php 
try{
    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `articles` ORDER BY publicationDate DESC LIMIT 0,5';
    $result = $pdo->query($sql);
} catch (PDOException $e){
    $error = 'Error fetching jokes: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
<div class="jumbotron">
    <div class="container">
    <?php 
        while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    ?>
    <h1><?php echo $row['id']; ?></h1>
    <p><?php echo $row['summary']; ?></p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <!-- Example row of columns -->
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $row['summary']; ?> </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $row['summary']; ?> </p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <h2><?php echo $row['title']; ?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $row['summary']; ?></p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">View details &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

To stop echoing duplicates, you can add the `<div>` wrappers based on the keys of your `$articles`:

```
   <?php
    // Loop through articles
    foreach ($articles as $key => $article) {
        // If first place, insert jumbotron class & container class
        if($key == 0) { ?>
    <div class="jumbotron">
        <div class="container">
        <?php }
        // Not 1st, just add rows
        else { 
                // If second place, add container class
                if($key == 1) { ?><div class="container"><?php } ?>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
        <?php } ?>
            <h1><?php htmlout($article['title'] ); ?></h1>
            <p><?php htmlout($article['summary'] );?></p>
            <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#" role="button">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
        </div>
    </div>
      <?php
      // If last place, add container class end
      if($key == 4) { ?></div><?php }
   }; ?>
```